# Clearing recommendations in the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

Due to <s>some careless browsing</s> being hacked, <sub>definitely hacked</sub>, my Play Store recommended apps are somewhat NSFW...

I looked in privacy settings for my Google account, but only found the option for search.

Is there some way to clear those recommendations or do I have to just keep browsing and installing other apps?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (based on past 'hacks') that the search history and installed apps are the two sources Google uses to make recommendations.

If you go to Settings and Clear Search History that should help, also if you go to My Apps, swipe left and click the x by the offending NSFW apps.